# nginx $host mapping with subdir_path

Tags: nginx

I tried solve this problem using nginx:

I have multiple folders under /var/www/html as:

```
/var/www/html/abc.example.com
/var/www/html/cde.example.com
/var/www/html/ghi.example.com
```

in nginx how to configure $host mapping to the directory so that if I open abc.example.com , it redirects to `abc.example.com` **folder** automatically. Also, I dont want to modify nginx configuration file if I add xyz.example.com so the $host mapping should be mapped to subdir_path and it only works when $host= directory path.

if I open `mnw.example.com` and if the folder with same name does not exists.. if should not work.

```
map $http_host $subdir {
    "~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$"    $domain;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        # Remove the www prefix (optional)
        if ($http_host ~* "^www\.(.*)$") {
            set $host_without_www $1;
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
        }

        # Serve the content from the corresponding directory
        try_files $uri $uri/ @subdir_index;
    }

    location @subdir_index {
        # Construct the path to the corresponding directory
        set $subdir_path "/var/www/html/$subdir$uri";

        # Check if the directory corresponding to the host exists
        if (-d $subdir_path) {
            # Serve the index.html from the corresponding directory
            rewrite ^ $subdir_path/index.html last;
        }

        # Serve the default index.html
        rewrite ^ /index.html last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `root /var/www/html/$subdir;` instead of the `if`s and `set`s?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with very simple setup. Improved answer given by @richard Smith above

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/$http_host;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```